# How do you start a simulation with a random initial state in Cirq?

Tags: programming, cirq

How do you create a random initial state by modifying the $2^{n}$ vector amplitudes instead of starting every simulation at $|0000...000\rangle$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a random computational basis state, set the input state to the integer `random.randint(0, 2**qubits-1)`.

If you want a random superposition sampled from the Haar measure, there is a method `cirq.testing.random_superposition(dim=2**qubits)`.

Once you have created your initial state, you pass it into the simulator like `cirq.Simulator().simulate(circuit, initial_state=...)`. Note that `run` methods do not support an initial state, because they are supposed to more closely mimic the hardware.